# Buffering between YouTube videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, iframe, youtube

Instead of working with 2 YouTube iFrame API players at a time (playing on one while buffering then playing on the second one and then switching and doing the same on the first one) is there a better way?

Playing videos on one and using the second one for buffering would be a lot cleaner and lot less error prone implementation if it worked - that is one player does not seem to be aware of what the other one has buffered.

All of this ends up even more important when slicing and splicing together a stream of shorter sub-sections from numerous videos because the buffering spinner ends up popping up much more often.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This is a great idea! I'm going to work on this (hopefully) in the next week..I'll post more

Comment: waiting for that post :)

Answer (score 1):

First you would need to use [Youtube's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086260/youtube-player-api-how-to-get-duration-of-a-loaded-cued-video-without-playing-i) to get the duration of each song (then maybe put it in a database) if you haven't already.

If you want to use two players, I would suggest using Tikku's [tubeplayer jquery plugin](http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin) . It works wonders with youtube's jquery API. you could set a function and delay playing (and then pausing once buffer starts - also easy with Tubeplayer) after 90% of the current song has played.

that's just an idea