# How I can extract video duration from youtub html page?

Tags: html, youtube, extract

I want to extract video duration from source of youtube video, Is that possible?
I have punch of of youtube URLs and I want to assign every URL to its duration.
I have tried from HTML source but all I get is from related video results not the main one

Comment: You can use youtube API, refer this. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086260/youtube-player-api-how-to-get-duration-of-a-loaded-cued-video-without-playing-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you can get all infos about a youtube video with PHP:

http://www.techtweaker.com/how-to-get-youtube-video-info-with-php/