# Write length of youtube iframe video to page

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to write the length of a youtube video on to a page. This page needs to by dynamic so when people create pages it looks for the src of the iframe, go to the youtube api, and find the duration of that video.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Wn5HxXKQOjw" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="video-length"></div>
```

```
// take the video id

var apiKey = xxx;
var videoURL = $('.wp-block-embed-youtube iframe').attr('src').substring(30, 41);
```

I've been looking at the documentation but couldn't find any examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YouTube Player API: How to get duration of a loaded/cued video without playing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086260/youtube-player-api-how-to-get-duration-of-a-loaded-cued-video-without-playing-i)

Comment: I saw that one. It kinda looks like what I want but really don't know how to implement it.